# Do followers of Hanuman have to be celibate?

Tags: hanuman

The God Hanuman is such a strict celibate, I wonder whether his disciples too should follow his path. Can someone please illuminate on this?

Comment: there is no 'have to', its upto you. But some food for thought is the celibacy is an internal battle to be won, rather than external. One can be married and lead the life of a householder, but still be free of lust (thus celibate). This is the kind of celibacy (internal celibacy, externally one may be a celibate or a householder, doesn't matter) that Lord Hanuman loves the best sir IMHO. All the best.

Comment: I don't think it should be a problem to Lord Hanuman Ji whether a devotee is celibate or not as he has been with married people all around all his life. Don't He liked his father and mother being married, don't he liked Lord Rama and Devi Sita to be married or Did he loved them being separated. The answer is clearly No. He has no problems with other people being married or unmarried. If he had any issues with others celibacy then He wouldn't have helped Lord Rama in getting Devi Sita back.

Comment: Its actually about personal choice whether you want to be a celibate or married. Lord Hanuman wanted his life to be dedicated to worshipping and servicing Lord Rama so he remained celibate may be also because he would then have no change in dedication/duty towards Lord Rama. Some people have started following him in wrong way that to be a celibate as a rule for worshipping Lord Hanuman. Also there are some people, who use to follow traits of their favourite God in their own lives in a way to convey to God that they are following him in deeds, thinking, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Hanuman is the God of family, he protects the family just like he saved Lord Ram's family. So, it is not that a devotee of Shri Hanuman cannot have a family.
**The answer to this questions is yes**, Hanumaan bhakt (disciples) must celibate but this is until they get married. While they are into kishoravastha (youth), they should take fasts on Tuesday, celibate and pray to Lord Ram.

sources: Personal experience.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  Personal experience is not an adequate source for this site.  You should cite a reliable source so people can verify that your answer is correct.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Please read the question, it asks personal opinions...
And there are no boundations on a devotee if he is a good man.

Comment: The question doesn't ask for personal opinions, and in any case opinion-based questions aren't allowed on this site.  So you should add reliable sources to your answer or it's liable to be deleted.

Comment: Ok, will make sure to find sources :-)

Comment: @ABcDexter Could you found the sources?